# how to parse a packet of unkown size from tcp socket in c

Tags: c, sockets, tcp, packet

I am trying to send a packet over a TCP socket. The structure that I am sending through the socket is the following:

```
struct requestPacket {
    uint32_t INDEX;
    uint32_t KEYSIZE;
    uint8_t *KEY; 
};
```

I send the packet (after having it placed in a buffer) in one go through a TCP socket with `send`:

```
send(sockfd, buff, size, 0);
```

Without knowing the size beforehand how can the server process this message? In the `recv` function, you have to define a buffer of a set size but you only know of this size after you process the beginning of the packet. Any tips? Is it possible to parse a packet twice? I know that the first 8 bytes will contain the index and the size of the message.

Comment: The receiving side knows the packet "header" contains two 32-bit values, of which one is the size. So it can read those eight bytes, place them into the structure, and now it has the size of the "key" data, and know how much more to it needs to receive.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude first off, love the name. Second, how would this translate to code? Could i do ```recv(sockfd, buff, 8, 0) ``` and follow up with ```recv(sockfd, buff, keysize,0)```?

Comment: *"I send the packet (after having it placed in a buffer) __in one go__ through a TCP socket with send"* - this might be an illusion. TCP is a byte stream not a message protocol. send can actually result in a short write where only parts of the data are written. You need to check the return value to find out how much was written and if not all is written you need to do another send (and maybe yet another one etc) for the rest of the data.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich by return value are you talking the return value of the send function or the recv function ? If it is a stream of bytes how can one be able to differentiate different packets if i send multiple times?

Comment: @a_confused_student: Both `send` can send less then given and `recv` can receive less then asked for. You need to check the return values in both cases. *"how can one be able to differentiate different packets"* - you can't. Also, don't assume that `send` results in a single packet. It can result in one, multiple, can be merged with previous or next `send` into one packet etc. Again, TCP provides only the semantic of a byte stream, not a sequence of messages or packets. Any semantic on top of the byte stream must be in your application protocol.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich say I'm sending packet by packet and I do a single``` recv``` of size 8, and I do a second ```recv``` of the remaining size will I be reading the beginning of the same packet or the rest of the packet?

Comment: @a_confused_student Yes something like that. But as others mentioned you need to both call `send` and `recv` in loops to make sure you get all. Even just for eight bytes you might not get all in one call.

Comment: @a_confused_student: *"say I'm sending packet by packet"* - the point is that you don't. Like I said, a single `send` is not necessarily equivalent to a single packet on the wire. In any way at the receiver end it is a byte stream only no matter how it was packetized on the wire. Each `recv` will return some bytes from the top of this byte stream and remove it from the byte stream (unless `recv` is combined with MSG_PEEK).

Answer (score 1):

A very simple method is to first read 8 bytes from the socket to get the size (appropriately converted to the host endianness), then allocate `size` bytes for the key and read size bytes.

Remember however that the packet may have been sliced and diced on its way from the client to the server, so multiple calls to `recv` or `read` may be required to read both the initial 8 bytes and the remaining size bytes.

You won't be reading the same *packet* twice. A TCP socket is a stream of bytes, you can read it in multiple chunks, just like a file, except you cannot seek. As a matter of fact, there is no need for the client to construct a buffer, it can issue 2 writes, one for the 8 byte header, and another one for the key contents. Conversely, the server may need more than one read for both the header and the key: a `read` request for 8 bytes may return a smaller count. Wrapping the socket in a `FILE` with `fdopen` is recommended.

Comment: with which function can this be done?

Comment: @a_confused_student `read` or `recv` as stated in the answer.

Comment: how can I ensure that I am reading the same packet twice?

Comment: If you are using TCP, you will _never_ be reading the same packet twice.

Comment: You won't be reading the same *packet* twice. A TCP socket is a stream of bytes, you can read it in multiple chunks, just like a file, except you cannot seek. As a matter of fact, there is no need for the client to construct a buffer, it can issue 2 writes, one for the 8 byte header, and another one for the key contents. The serveur may need more than one read for both the header and the key: a `read` request for 8 bytes may return a smaller count. Wrapping the socket in a `FILE` with `fdopen` is recommended.

Comment: I have started to do a recv of a size 8 but when doing so I get stack smashing detected how can I pass through this?

Comment: @a_confused_student: there must be a bug in your code... You should post the code in another question.